# "Non-value field is accessed in 'hashCode()" Intellij error, scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, hashcode

quick question. I'm getting a warning in my Scala project in IntelliJ Idea, here's the error and the code:

Code:

```
override def hashCode: Int = tinyVal.hashCode
```

Error:

```
"Non-value field is accessed in 'hashCode()"
```

The reason I'm doing this is because I want calls of hashCode on the class to always take the hashcode of a field inside the class.

Comment: You  need to show us what `tinyVal` is. From the error, it's probably not a `val`?

Comment: I turned it into a val and that removed the warning. Thanks.